# Give unique child Key value for User using Firebase push() Method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to give user defined key value in `push()`, instead of unique value created by push?

This is what am currently doing:

```
User user = new User(Editname.getText().toString(),
      Editpid.getText().toString(),Editsem.getText().toString());

mRef.child("users").push().setValue(user);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.push()` will create a new item with a unique reference.

You can use `updateChildren()` to update instead. For example,

```
User user=new User(Editname.getText().toString(),Editpid.getText().toString(),Editsem.getText().toString()); 
Map<String, Object> itemValues = user.toMap();
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

// Define the key value here
String username = "yourKeyValueHere";
childUpdates.put("/users/" + username, itemValues);
mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

You might have to add something similar to the following to your User class.

```
@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("name", name);
    result.put("pid", pid);
    result.put("sem", sem);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to specify the child key with the `child` method:

```
User user = new User(Editname.getText().toString(),
     Editpid.getText().toString(),Editsem.getText().toString());

mRef.child("users").child(user.pid).setValue(user);
```

Where I specify `user.pid`, you can use whatever unique key you use to identify the user (typically when using Firebase Authentication this would be `user.getUid()`).

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it assuming we want to use the User's name as unique key:

```
User user = new User(Editname.getText().toString(),
  Editpid.getText().toString(),Editsem.getText().toString());

 String uniqueKey = user.getName();
 //You could use something else for quick reference since two users can have the same name
 mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(uniqueKey).push().setValue(user);
```